# Как принять ajax запрос

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

1. Объясните, что находится в функции `file_get_contents('<b>php://input</b>')`. Что есть `php://input`?
2. Подскажите, как принять в php файле запрос ajax.

Answer (score 1):

ajax мало чем отличается от обычного запроса. Передавайте в качестве запроса строку `param=value&param2=value2`, а потом читайте `$_POST['param']`, `$_POST['param2']` и т.д.
Если передаете просто текст без переменных, то можно читать просто `$_POST` как строку.

Comment: php://input а это что есть?